# Redo a function using else

Tags: python, python-3.x

So i have created a function and inside i had put an if command, to check for the answer, but when the answer is invalid i want to repeat the function so it asks again. It is supposed to ask for either input A or B but when for eg i put C it should call back on the function and repeat. How do i make it re-ask for the input? This is what i tried:

```
def function():
    data = input("A/B")
    if data == "A":
        print("A")
    elif data == "B":
        print("B")
    else:
        function()   #<-----problem here
```

Comment: [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/953482) may be of interest to you.

Comment: Seems working. What's wrong?

Comment: File "C:/Users//tsav1.py", line 30, in function
    function()
NameError: name 'function' is not defined

Comment: Call your function after you define it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample code you posted works the way you have described you want it to. For more complicated functions involving returning values, I would recommend writing and calling it this way:

```
def function():
    data = input("A/B")
    if data == "A":
        return("A")
    elif data == "B":
        return("B")
    else:
        return(function())

print(function())
```

What this means:

```
return(function())
```

is that the function will return the result of the next call of the function. That next call may in turn return the result of the *next call* of the function. This concept is a major part of [recursion](https://pythonspot.com/recursion/) which may be worth looking into for future use.

Answer (score 0):

try while loop:

```
ans="C"
while ans!="B" and ans!="A":
    ans=input("A/B")   
print(ans)
```

Comment: But your way is also correct...(I have tried to run it here: http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=display)

Comment: Don't initialize `ans` to `"C"`, if he wants to add `C` as a valid value in the future, this can lead to problems (use empty string for initialization `ans=""`). Also, with your code, inputting `a` would ask for input again which is probably not the wanted behavior. Use `while ans.upper() not in {"A","B"}:` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Recursive function.  For building one just call with return:

```
Else:
    return function()
```

You can insert the function in a var:

```
var = function()
```

And call it:

```
return var
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem you don't need to call the function again as if the user inputs wrong answer too many time (some big number I forgot) it will reach the stack limit. To solve your problem you can simple use a while loop. The code below shows how this can be done:

```
def function():
    while True: 
        data = input("A/B") 
        if data == "A": 
            print("A") 
            return
        elif data == "B": 
            print("B")
            return
```

As you can see from the code above, we are using a infinite while loop which will keep looping untill user inputs 'A' or a 'B'. If you don't know the keyword return can be used to exist out of a function before hand.

Also I was using my phone to answer this question so if I made any mistakes sorry about that.